# When I hit history on a Linux server machine unable to view date and time

Tags: shell-script

I have tried below method 10 times and unable to find the exact time and date of the command in history.

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T'
```

By running above command it shows only current date and time not the actual date and time of the command.

Can anyone help how to get the exact date and time of the commands in the history.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `HISTTIMEFORMAT` will not retrospectively set the correct timestamps for all the commands in your history, as these have never been recorded, it will show everything which was loaded from your `~/.bash_history` as the time your shell process started.

All commands you have run in that session and commands you run after setting `HISTTIMEFORMAT` will have the correct timestamp.

Edit:
It should also be noted that shell history should not be relied on as accurate or as an audit of what has happened on the system, it is just there for the convenience of the user. Shell history is easily removed or edited and is especially unreliable when you have multiple shells open at the same time.

Comment: It probably should be mentioned that the shell history is not designed to be an auditing tool for the system administrator, but as a convenience feature for the user's own use. If you need a record of who-did-what-when that is unambiguous and not modifiable by the user, you should set up the audit subsystem or a session recorder instead.